# How to use .map function to generate array from a schema

Tags: javascript, dictionary, recursion

I have been working on a way to generate a array from a schema. I am almost there I am getting the strings pushed to the array but on when it iterates over the next field it initialises the array again and I am unsure of how to fix it.

I have included a sandbox that has the issue.
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-architecture-i94ph?file=/src/App.js

the output I want should be `[contractorName, agencyName]`

currently it is outputting
`log1 [contractorName]`
`log2 [agencyName]`
`log3 []`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is, that you declare your `watchingArray` in `generateWatchedFields` everytime you call `generateWatchedFields`.

```
export const generateWatchedFields = (schema) => {
  const watchingArray = []; // New array on every call

  Object.values(schema).map((propertySchema) => {
    if (propertySchema.properties) {
      return generateWatchedFields(propertySchema.properties);
    } else if (propertySchema.dependencies) {
      const push = propertySchema.dependencies.watching;
      return watchingArray.push(push);
    } else {
      console.log(watchingArray);
    }
  });
  console.log(watchingArray);
  return watchingArray;
};
```

So you just need to declare it outside of this context, like this:

```
var watchingArray = [];

export const generateWatchedFields = (schema) => {    
  Object.values(schema).map((propertySchema) => {
    if (propertySchema.properties) {
      return generateWatchedFields(propertySchema.properties);
    } else if (propertySchema.dependencies) {
      const push = propertySchema.dependencies.watching;
      return watchingArray.push(push);
    } else {
      console.log(watchingArray);
    }
  });
  console.log(watchingArray);
  return watchingArray;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
export const generateWatchedFields = (schema) => {
  const watchingArray = [];

  function iterates(schema){

  
    Object.values(schema).map((propertySchema) => {
      if (propertySchema.properties) {
        iterates(propertySchema.properties);
      } else if (propertySchema.dependencies) {
        const push = propertySchema.dependencies.watching;
        watchingArray.push(push);
      } else {
        console.log(watchingArray);
      }
    });
    console.log(watchingArray);
  }

  iterates(schema)

  return watchingArray;
};
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for but it returns ["contractorName", "agencyName"]